# Generating patches in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I've looked for that in the manual, but I can't generate a patch for the last commit.
I tried

```
hg qnew patch_name
```

but it does only file with

```
# HG changeset patch
# Parent a6a8e225d16ff5970a8926ee8d24272a1c099f9c
```

I also tried

```
hg export tip
```

but it doesn't do anything. I committed the changes exactly.

How to generate a patch file with the last commit in?

Comment: `hg diff -c tip > patch`  -- note that qnew is part of the mq extension and is for a different purpose.

Comment: If you've already done a `qnew` with no changes then the tip revision will be empty when you do `export tip`. You'll need to do qdel to delete the patches you have applied.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The command to do this is `export`:

```
$ hg export -o FILE -r REV
```

It doesn't require redirection and will thus work correctly on any platform/shell.

Comment: Also it outputs the changeset headers like user and date that Mercurial can use to reconstruct the changeset when importing it later.

Answer (score 22):

Your `hg export tip` is the best way to do it, and the `hg diff` and `hg log` based answers are just lesser versions of the same.  What exactly do you see/get when you type `hg export tip`?  What does the output of `hg log -p -r tip` show?

The changeset `tip` is just means "the changeset that most recently arrived in my repository" which isn't as useful a concept as you might think, since `hg pull` and `hg tag` all create changesets too.  If you really want the last thing you committed you'll need a more precise `revspec`.

Comment: +1 for explaining what tip means which is a likely misconception.

Answer (score 18):

Like so:

```
hg diff -r tip > tip.patch
```

Comment: I entered it in the windows console, but it creates empty file. Even, the "hg diff" command doesn't return anything.

Comment: There's a nice UI for this in TortoiseHG.  Try `hg diff -c tip > tip.patch` instead of `-r`.

Comment: @WarrenP OK, I open the revision history window, and what next? How to generate a file with any revision?

Comment: My colleague did like this on his PC and it does not work to import the patch on my pc, so it is not working

Comment: I believe this is how to make a ptach for an _uncommitted_ change.  A related valuable tip but not what the OP asked.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this command:

```
hg log -r tip -p > tip.patch
```

this will generate a patch for just that revision.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to **convert** the latest commit to a patch file, use

```
hg qimport -r tip
```

This will replace the topmost regular commit with an applied MQ patch file.

Answer (score 0):

To generate patches using "mq extensions" in mercurial, you can follow the below given steps. This will create a patch using mercurial:

1) Enabling mq extensions: Add the following lines to your hgrc file and save it.

```
[extensions]
mq =
```

2) Creating a patch using mq extensions: To create a patch using mq extensions you can do the following.

```
hg qnew -e -m "comment you want to enter" bug_name.patch
```

In the above command, ***-e*** flag is for editing the patch and ***-m*** flag is for adding a message to the patch.

3) Updating the patch: For updating the patch, you can use the following command when a patch is already applied.

```
hg qrefresh
```